# How to get the maximum value from the HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML looks like:

```
<ul>
  <li data-target="12">1</li>
  <li data-target="4">2</li>
  <li data-target="9">3</li>
  <li data-target="15">4</li>
  <li data-target="23">5</li>
  <li data-target="32">6</li>
  <li data-target="7">7</li>
  <li data-target="10">8</li>
  <li data-target="5">9</li>
  <li data-target="2">10</li>
</ul>
```

What method should I use to get the maximum value from the `data-target` attributes? Do vanilla JavaScript or jQuery have some native functions for this or I should just use `for` loop to iterate through all the items and get the maximum value, shouldn't I?

Comment: Have you tried to do this at least with `for`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way (without bothering with an array);

```
var max = 0;
$("li[data-target]").each(function() {
    max = Math.max(max, parseInt($(this).data("target"), 10));
});

alert(max);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this: use [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) along with [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) function:

```
var targets = $("li").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("target");
}).get();
var max = Math.max.apply(Math,targets);
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zxd0zct6/)

Answer (score 3):

use [`Math.max.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) method to get max value from a numeric array.

```
var arr = $('li[data-target]').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('target')
});
console.log(Math.max.apply(Math,arr));
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qteq04m6/)**

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```js
var array = []; 
$('li').each(function() {
    array.push($(this).data('target'));
});
var maxNumber = Math.max.apply(Math, array);

alert(maxNumber);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-target="12">1</li>
<li data-target="4">2</li>
<li data-target="9">3</li>
<li data-target="15">4</li>
<li data-target="23">5</li>
<li data-target="32">6</li>
<li data-target="7">7</li>
<li data-target="10">8</li>
<li data-target="5">9</li>
<li data-target="2">10</li>
```

Comment: The map is more elegant :))

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxVal = 0;
$('[data-target]').each(
    function(){
        if($(this).attr('data-target') > maxVal){
            maxVal = $(this).attr('data-target');
        }
    });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgrm3qjk/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
var maxValue = 0;

$("li").each(function(index,val){
  var value = $(this).attr('data-target');   
    if(value > maxValue) maxValue= value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get max value using `for each loop` of jquery. For each value of li get its attribute `data-target`. e.g

```
  var maxVal=0;
 $(this).find('li').each(function(){
            // cache jquery var
            var current = $(this);
            var val=parseInt(current.attr( "data-target" ));
            if(val > maxVal){
               maxVal=val;
            }       
        });
        console.log(maxVal);//Its the max value
```

Answer (score 0):

Turak Vladyslav

below code will work you can check it once

```js
var Lis = $('#test').find('li');
var dataArray = []
for(var i=0;i<Lis.length;i++){
 dataArray.push($(Lis[i]).attr('data-target'))
  
}
var maxDatatTarget = Math.max.apply(null, dataArray)
alert("max data target value"+maxDatatTarget)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test">
<li data-target="12">1</li>
<li data-target="4">2</li>
<li data-target="9">3</li>
<li data-target="15">4</li>
<li data-target="23">5</li>
<li data-target="32">6</li>
<li data-target="7">7</li>
<li data-target="10">8</li>
<li data-target="5">9</li>
<li data-target="2">10</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works for you :

```
function calculateMaxTarget(){

  var attr[] = $('li').attr('data-target');
  var max = 0;
  for (var i=0; i < attr.length; i++) {
    if(attr[i]>max){
      max = attr[i];
    }
  };
  return max;
}
```